# Naming destructured argument objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With ES6, one can destructure argument objects like this:

```
function myFun ( {val1, val2, val3} ) {
    console.log("easy access to individual entries: ", val2);
}
```

But is it also possible to simultaneously name the whole argument object, such that I can refer to this directly as well? I have tried using the 'arguments' object for this purpose, but with little success (that particular issue I'll save for another question here, if need be)